# Add to an ArrayList using the get method

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, get

What is the most appropriate way to add to an ArrayList using values from the get method.

I'm aware the below line of code is an error,  I can't figure what's wrong in it.

```
System.out.println("List of Foods");
List<String> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
foodList.addAll(getId(), getDescription(), getIngredients(), getSellingPrice());
System.out.println(foodList);
```

Error Message:

```
 Multiple markers at this line
    - Occurrence of 'addAll'
    - The method addAll(int, Collection<? extends String>) in the type List<String> is not applicable 
     for the arguments (int, String, List<String>, double)
    - 1 changed line
```

The idea behind is to be able to retrieve these user input in the main method and display it using the below code

```
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
System.out.printf("%5s %15s %20s %30s", "FOOD ID", "DESCRIPTION", "SELLING PRICE", "INGREDIENTS" + "\n"); 
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");

//iterates over the list   
for (Food food : foods) {
    System.out.format("%5s %15s %20s %30s", food.getId(), food.getDescription(), food.getSellingPrice(), food.getIngredients());
    System.out.println(); 
}
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

get() methods definition:

```
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public double getSellingPrice() {
    return sellingPrice;
}

public List<String> getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}
```

I have changed the following line of codes:

```
System.out.println("List of Foods");
                List<String> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
                foodList.add(getId());
                foodList.add(getDescription());
                foodList.addAll(getIngredients());
                foodList.add(getSellingPrice());
                System.out.println(foodList);
```

and I have changed the existing Food class:

```
public class Food {

private String  id;
private String description;
private String sellingPrice;
private List<String> ingredients;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public Food(String id, String description, String sellingPrice, List<String> ingredients) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.description = description;
    this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
```

After some adjustments, a new issue arise with the following code:

```
                case 2:
                System.out.println("List of Foods");
                List<Object> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
                foodList.add(getId());
                foodList.add(getId());
                foodList.add(getDescription());
                foodList.addAll(getIngredients());
                foodList.add(getSellingPrice());
                System.out.println(foodList);

                List<Object> food1 = new ArrayList<>();
                food1.add(foodList);
                
                List<Object> food2 = new ArrayList<>();
                food2.add(foodList);
                
                List<Object> food3 = new ArrayList<>();
                food3.add(foodList);
                
                
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.printf("%5s %15s %20s %31s", "FOOD ID", "DESCRIPTION", "SELLING PRICE(Rs)", "INGREDIENTS" + "\n"); 
                System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                
                for (Object  food : foodList) {
                    System.out.format("%5s %17s %20s %30s", getId(), getDescription(), getSellingPrice(), getIngredients());
                    System.out.println(); 
                    
                }
                break;
```

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/425kP.png)

1 - is for adding food items
2- is for display

Comment: please share methods `getId(), getDescription(), getIngredients(), getSellingPrice()` that you use in addAlll

Comment: How do you thing about going from a list of String to a list of Food, please share Good class too, we need to be able to reproduce the code

Comment: That the problem this line of code `List<String> foodList = new ArrayList<>();`  is defined with different datatypes

Comment: That's not [how `addAll` is called](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-). Try looking at [ArrayList addAll() method example](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/arraylist-addall-method-example/).

Comment: where does the data from ? how to create a Food : with user input ? `getId()` is method to call on en existing Food, but you seems to call to create one, there is lot a unknown things here it seels

Comment: What're the problems with your current code?

Comment: I just saw you last question closed, I'll answere here, that will be a real working answer that you will be able to accept ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed a lot of things in your head, let's clarify some

Define a `Food` class, that have `get` methods, it doesn't need the `set` ones

```java
class Food {

    private int id;
    private String description;
    private String sellingPrice;
    private List<String> ingredients;

    public Food(int id, String description, String sellingPrice, List<String> ingredients) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) { // JUST FOR EXAMPLE, you don't need the set method
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public String getSellingPrice() {
        return sellingPrice;
    }
    public List<String> getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%5s %17s %20s %30s", id, description, sellingPrice, ingredients);
    }
}
```

Then a main class, no matter it's name with, custom methods to ask user input

```java
class Main {
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("How many food do you want to register ?");
        int count = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        List<Food> foods = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            foods.add(new Food(generateId(), generateDescription(), generateSellingPrice(), generateIngredients()));
        }

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.printf("%5s %15s %20s %31s", "FOOD ID", "DESCRIPTION", "SELLING PRICE(Rs)", "INGREDIENTS" + "\n");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        for (Food food : foods) {
            System.out.println(food);
            // System.out.format("%s", food.getId()); // if toString wasn't implemented you'd that
        }
    }

    private static int generateId() {
        System.out.println("Input food ID");
        return Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    }

    private static String generateDescription() {
        System.out.println("Input food name");
        return sc.nextLine();
    }

    private static String generateSellingPrice() {
        System.out.println("Input food Price");
        return sc.nextLine();
    }

    private static List<String> generateIngredients() {
        List<String> ingredients = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of Ingredients to add: ");
        int ingredientCount = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < ingredientCount; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter an ingredient: ");
            ingredients.add(sc.nextLine());
        }
        return ingredients;
    }
}
```

Comment: I did manage to make it work, with some minor changes, with the  `toString` method. will try the next remaining parts, Linear Search and Binary search, I guess you will be hearing from me soon.... lol

Answer (score 2):

Assume the getId(), getDescription(), getIngredients(), getSellingPrice() methods was reading user input.

You will need to create a Food class to hold these values and have an ArrayList of Food for the display logic.

Pseudo code

```
public class Food{
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private String ingredients;
    private double sellingPrice;
    // Constructor, Getter, Setter
}


List<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<>();
String id = getId()
String description = getDescription()
String ingredients = getIngredients()
double sellingPrice = getSellingPrice()
Food food = new Food(id, description, ingredients, sellingPrice)

foodList.add(food);
```